# Import/Call class vb.net from external .vb file

Tags: vb.net, function, file, split, partial-classes

I have a pretty big VB.net code and I am trying to split it into different files. I want to create an external file containing different functions. I have read about partial class files but it is not working for me. Is there any option to call/import a vb.net file and do something as per below example?

Example

---

Form1.vb

---

```
' Imports Functions.vb (How can I call the file containing the class?)

Public Class Form1

Dim a,b,y As Double
Dim calculate As New MyFunctions

a=1
b=1

y=calculate.sum(a,b)

End Class
```

---

Functions.vb

---

```
Partial Class MyFunctions

Public Function sum(a As Double, b As Double) As Double

     return a+b

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio IDE (Integrated Development Environment)?  It should be pretty easy, just add a code module and move some of your functions into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the functions to be available to all your code, just create a module with the functions in them.

If you just want to split your form1 class into separate files, your form1 file should contain the class definition ..

```
Partial Public Class Form1
```

To create a new file for the bits you want to separate off, create a new class file and change the default definition to the above.

Please note that you might need to add `Imports` lines for each files as well.

In and old project of mine, I had a single form program but had the code split into several files such as ExcelFileHandling.vb, EmailHandling.vb etc. They were all actually partial definitions of Form1. Easy peasy :-)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [Imports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type) statement when you don't want to fully qualify a namespace of a class.  If the other class is in the same namespace as the class that is referencing it, there is no need to use Imports.
Note, that your example code has functionality that should exist in a method instead of in the body of the class.

```
'RootNamespace = Right click on project file and choose properties.  You'll see it defined there.
Imports RootNamespace.SomeOtherNamespace

Namespace SomeNamespace

    Public Class Form 1

        Public Sub SomeMethod()

            Dim objMyFunctions As New MyFunctions()
            'If no Imports is used: As New SomeOtherNamespace.MyFunctions()

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace

Namespace SomeOtherNamespace

    Public Class MyFunctions

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Example if both classes are in the same Namespace:

```
Public Class MyFunctions

    Public Sub SomeMethod()

        'No need for Imports because they are in the same Namespace.
        Dim objMyFunctions As New MyFunctions()

    End Sub 

End Class

Public Class MyFunctions

End Class
```